# How can one change the header comment auto generated by eclipse?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, header-files, eclipse-cdt

The Eclipse CDT generates comments in header files that look a lot like this:

```
/*
 * Foo.hpp
 *
 *  Created on: Mar 27, 2017
 *      Author: jeremiah
 */
```

How does one change that header?   I simply want it to include the normal "This-file-is-protected-by-this-licence" type stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file header comment can be set here:

Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Code Templates -> Comments -> Files